# Vdebug / Xdebug only showing first 32 elements of arrays

Tags: vim, xdebug

I'm new to using Xdebug via the Vim plugin [Vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/blob/master/doc/Vdebug.txt).

I'm getting on OK, but I noticed that if I create an array with over 32 elements, the Watch window only shows elements 0-31 (i.e. the first 32). There does not seem to be a way to obtain the next 32, or to tell it to fetch all of them (or 1000 of them or whatever)?

Is this a bug/feature-lack in Vdebug? Is there anything I can do about it?

I'm debugging Drupal, which has very big, complex arrays (which sometimes contain recursive references #sigh), so at first I thought maybe it's iterating, getting in a loop and hitting max data limit. But I tried just looking at `for ($i=0;$i<50;$i++) $a[] = $i;` and this, too, only lists elements 0-31.

I have tried

```
let g:vdebug_features['max_depth'] = 1000
let g:vdebug_features['max_data']  = 1000000
```

but they have not made any difference.

Thanks,

Comment: Use the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/issues).

Answer (score 4):

After Vdebug is loaded, put this

```
let g:vdebug_features = { 'max_children': 128 }
```

Or whatever you'd like your max to be.

All credit to [romaini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) for this answer as it was his comment that meant I found this problem listed as an [issue](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/issues/59) on the vdebug github repo.